# Android Sqlite data records View on swipe

Tags: sqlite, android-viewpager

I want to add a dynamic viewpager in my application which show Sqlite database records one by one on swipe from left to right please help me in developing this.
i don't know how to configure fragments and add multiple labels to it show database records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` and to get data from Sqlite database you can use `CursorAdapter` class. For more information please look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162589/viewpager-cursor-and-fragment) link which might help you to get your desired result.

Comment: Well my problem is this my records are dynamic so how i change view accordingly on swipe if you a provide a code snippet that would be a great help.

Comment: i USE FragmentPagerAdapter problem resolved swiping through database record by record.

Comment: View page adapter to set offset of swipes and to options of view PagerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

By using the concept of dynamic fragments and SQLlite database, manage a list of records containing student name, registration number, and current semester with degree title e.g. BSSE6/BSIT6/BSCS6. Please implement following functionalities:

1. Retrieve data of one class from database ordered by their registration number
2. Provide two buttons on slider fragment to mark PRESENT or ABSENT
3. Automatically slide to next student record when the user mark their attendance
4. List down a final attendance on students with some summary blocks in a fragment within same activity
   4.1 Summary blocks should contain total number of students, total present and absent students
   You can design your on layout without any limitations, but it should be decent and user friendly